# PDO PDOStatement::execute(): SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1008 OCIStmtExecute: ORA-01008: not all variables bound

Tags: php, oracle, pdo

I recently converted my website from OCI to PDO.

I have this PHP:

```
  foreach ($bindings as $key => $value) {
   if ( strpos( $query, $key) ) {
    $stmt->bindParam(":$key", $value);
    echo "Bound ". $key ." => ". $value;
   }
  }
```

Output:

```
Bound :globalSearch0 => %NCR%
Bound :globalSearch1 => %NCR%
Bound :globalSearch2 => %NCR%
Bound :globalSearch3 => %NCR%
Bound :globalSearch4 => %NCR%
```

but PHP still outputs error message:

> **Warning**:  PDOStatement::execute(): SQLSTATE[HY000]: General
>   error: 1008 OCIStmtExecute: ORA-01008: not all variables bound

but all variables **are** bound! I echo the SQL query generated and it is using 5 variables, the same amount that were bound!

Am I totally missing something here? This is the same code that I used `oci_bind_by_name` with and I never had any problems, but `bindParam` seems to be causing this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you array key already has ':' in it, do you need to add it again in the `bindParam` argument?

It should be `$stmt->bindParam($key, $value);`

To make your test accurate it should look like:

```
if( $stmt->bindParam(":$key", $value) ){
  echo "Bound ". $key ." => ". $value;
}
```

To make sure binding is actually successful